# How can I solve kafka timeout?

Tags: apache-kafka

I came to find an answer to my question while using kafka.

I am using `kafka version 2.1.0` and kafka connect together.

While I was using,

> [2019-02-24 13:23:17,056] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=2] Group topic name transitioned to Dead in generation 12 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)

The above error occurred on kafka broker and after that, both producer and consumer are being timeout because broker will not accept the request.

It will not shutdown with `kakfa-server-stop.sh`. It keeps restarting after killing the process forcefully. I think there is a deadlock somewhere, but what would be the reason?

I cannot understand because even if there is an error on kafka connect, it should not affect the broker.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the os? Is there any firewall running?

Comment: The os we are using is linux cent os 7.5.1804 (Core).  The firewall is running but i dont think it will be a problem since all servers are located in internal network. Kakfka network thread is not running well after timeout. I cannot find the reason. Its difficult. @SoheilPourbafrani

Answer (score 1):

finally, I found a solution. 
I've analyzed the thread dump, It was similar to the case of this 
 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7697

I upgraded kafka version from 2.1.0 to 2.1.1